# How to active the link when I click the link in Flask .plese give your valueble solution

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm using Python-Flask. I've been trying to activate the link in menu bar in my dashboard. I used Jinja2 in HTML template for active the link. But, it's not working.

Here is the dashboard menu bar snippet

[image]

Suppose, if click the entity management, it shows sub class links. When I click the link that link will be activated. I wrote Jinja2 code in `base.html` for active element.

Here is the `base.html` code:

```
<em class="fas fa-user-circle" style="margin-right:3px;">&nbsp;</em>EntityManagement<span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-1"></span>
</a></li>
<ul class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'entitymanagement' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-1">
    <li><a  class="{{ 'active' if active_page == '/page/newuser' else '' }}"   class="" href="/page/newuser" style="padding: 12px 12px;  " >
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;" >&nbsp</span>newuser
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/page/edituser" style="padding:12px 12px;"  >
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:12px;"  >&nbsp;</span>View/Edit User
    </a></li>
</ul>
 <li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"  >
    <em class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:8px;"></em>Enquiry Profile<span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"></span>
 </a></li>
<ul class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'enquiryprofile' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-2">
    <li class="{% block nav_home %}{% endblock %}"><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == '/page/enquiry' else '' }}"  class="" href="/page/enquiry" style="padding: 15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span> Create Enquiry
    </a></li>
    <li   style="padding:15px 15px"><a class="" href="/page/enquirydetails"  >
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>View/Edit Enquiry
    </a></li>
</ul>
 <li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-3"  >
    <em class="fab fa-quora" aria-hidden="true"  style="margin-right:8px;"></em>Quotations <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-3"></span>
</a></li>
<ul class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'quotations' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-3">
    <li><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == 'pagequotes' else '' }}" class="" href="/page/quotes" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span> Create Quote
    </a></li>
    <li ><a class="" href="/page/quotespage" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>View/Edit Quote
    </a></li>
</ul>
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-4"  >
    <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:12px;"></i>Driver <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-4"></span>
</a></li>
<ul  class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'driver' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-4">
    <li  class="active"><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == 'pagequotes' else '' }}"  class="" href="/static/driver" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span> Create Driver
    </a></li>
    <li class="active" ><a class="" href="/static/driverdetails" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>View/Edit Driver
    </a></li>
</ul>
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-5"  >
    <i class="fal fa-truck" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>TruckCompany<span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"></span>
</a></li>
<ul  class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'truckcompany' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-5">
    <li><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == 'static/truckcompany' else '' }}" class="" href="/static/truckcompany" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span> Create Truck
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/static/truckcompanyview" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>View/Edit Truck
    </a></li>
</ul>
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-6"  >
    <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"   aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>Locations<span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"></span>
</a></li>
<ul  class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'locations' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-6">
    <li><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == '/page/locations' else '' }}" class="" href="/page/locations" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span> Create Locations
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/page/locationviews" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>View/Edit Locations
    </a></li>
</ul>
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-7"  >
    <i class="fa fa-truck " width="1" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>Load Type<span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"></span>
</a></li>
<ul  class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'loadtype' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-7">
    <li class="active"><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == '/page/load' else '' }}" class="" href="/page/load" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span> Create Load
    </a></li>
    <li class="active"><a class="" href="/page/loadview" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>View/Edit
    </a></li>
</ul>
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-8"  >
    <i class="fa fa-truck " width="1" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>Vehicle Type<span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"></span>
</a></li>
<ul  class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'vehicletype' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-8">
    <li><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == '/page/vehicletype' else '' }}" class="" href="/static/vehicletype" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span> Create Vehicle Type
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/static/vehicletype_details" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>View/Edit Vehicle Type
    </a></li>
</ul>
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-9"  >
    <i class="fa fa-truck " width="1" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>Vehicle <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"></span>
</a></li>
<ul  class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'vehicle' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-9">
    <li><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == '/page/vehicle' else '' }}" class="" href="/static/vehicle" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span> Create Vehicle
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/static/vehicledetails" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>View/Edit Vehicle
    </a></li>
</ul>
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-10"  >
    <i class="fa fa-suitcase "  aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>Orders <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"></span>
</a></li>
<ul  class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'orders' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-10">
    <li><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == '/page/jobs' else '' }}" class="" href="/page/jobs" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span> Create Orders
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/page/jobspage" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>View/Edit Orders
    </a></li>
</ul>
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-11"  >
    <i class="fa fa-history " width="1" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>History <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"></span>
</a></li>
<ul class="children collapse" id="sub-item-11">
    <li><a class="" href="/page/jobs">
        <span class="fas fa-edit">&nbsp;</span>Orders History
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/page/oldjobspage">
        <span class="fas fa-eye">&nbsp;</span>View Orders History
    </a></li>
</ul>
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-12"  >
    <i class="fas fa-map-marker" width="1" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>Tracking <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"></span>
</a></li>
<ul  class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'tracking' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-12">
    <li><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == '/page/tracking' else '' }}" class="" href="/page/tracking" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>Tracking Location
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/page/trackingpage" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>Tracking History
    </a></li>
</ul>
<li class="parent "><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-13"  >
    <i class="fas fa-user" width="1" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>Driver Allocation <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2"></span>
</a></li>
<ul  class="{{ 'children collapse in' if active_block == 'driverallocation' else 'children collapse' }}" id="sub-item-13">
    <li><a class="{{ 'active' if active_page == '/page/driverallocation' else '' }}" class="" href="/page/driverallocation" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-edit" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>Create Driverallocation
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/page/allocationdetails" style="padding:15px 15px;">
        <span class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;</span>View/Edit Driverallocation
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the entity management `newuser.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% set active_block = "entitymanagement" %}
{% set active_page = '/page/newuser' %}
```

Here is the entity management `edituser.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% set active_block = "entitymanagement" %}
{% set active_page = '/page/newuser' %}
```

Comment: `edituser.html` and `newuser.html` hold the same values. Normal?

Comment: yes.it holds same values.